# ValueError with Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, model

*link to [car data.csv](https://github.com/marsianjohncarter/StackOverflow--Sklearn_ValueError)*

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
car_data = pd.read_csv('car_data.csv')

# Create X
X = car_data.drop('Buy Rate', axis=1)

# Create Y
y = car_data['Buy Rate']

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.get_params()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

After the line with `clf.fit`, this error pops up:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_51905/2395142735.py in ?()
----> 1 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

~/Desktop/ml-course/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in ?(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1147                 skip_parameter_validation=(
   1148                     prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1149                 )
   1150             ):
-> 1151                 return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

~/Desktop/ml-course/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py in ?(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    344         """
    345         # Validate or convert input data
    346         if issparse(y):
    347             raise ValueError("sparse multilabel-indicator for y is not supported.")
--> 348         X, y = self._validate_data(
    349             X, y, multi_output=True, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE
    350         )
    351         if sample_weight is not None:

~/Desktop/ml-course/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in ?(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, cast_to_ndarray, **check_params)
    617                 if "estimator" not in check_y_params:
    618                     check_y_params = {**default_check_params, **check_y_params}
    619                 y = check_array(y, input_name="y", **check_y_params)
    620             else:
--> 621                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    622             out = X, y
    623 
    624         if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):

~/Desktop/ml-course/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in ?(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
   1143         raise ValueError(
   1144             f"{estimator_name} requires y to be passed, but the target y is None"
   1145         )
   1146 
-> 1147     X = check_array(
   1148         X,
   1149         accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
   1150         accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,

~/Desktop/ml-course/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in ?(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    914                         )
    915                     array = xp.astype(array, dtype, copy=False)
    916                 else:
    917                     array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
--> 918             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    919                 raise ValueError(
    920                     "Complex data not supported\n{}\n".format(array)
    921                 ) from complex_warning

~/Desktop/ml-course/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_array_api.py in ?(array, dtype, order, copy, xp)
    376         # Use NumPy API to support order
    377         if copy is True:
    378             array = numpy.array(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    379         else:
--> 380             array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    381 
    382         # At this point array is a NumPy ndarray. We convert it to an array
    383         # container that is consistent with the input's namespace.

~/Desktop/ml-course/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in ?(self, dtype)
   2082     def __array__(self, dtype: npt.DTypeLike | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
   2083         values = self._values
-> 2084         arr = np.asarray(values, dtype=dtype)
   2085         if (
   2086             astype_is_view(values.dtype, arr.dtype)
   2087             and using_copy_on_write()

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Hyundai'
```

I have viewed similar questions that have been posted here, but none help.

Comment: What have you tried from those other questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error arises because your features(i.e.,Make and Color) in X is categorical, if you encode them into numerical variables using Label Encoder,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
car_data['Make'] = le.fit_transform(car_data['Make'])
car_data['Color'] = le.fit_transform(car_data['Color'])
```

then your result will be like this if `car_data.head(2)` is executed,

```
    Make    Year    Price   Mileage Color   Buy Rate
0   30      2018    20000   50000   1       0.80
1   13      2019    25000   40000   4       0.70
```

This solves your problem!

But since your target variable(i.e.,Buy Rate) is continuous, you will get an error while training your data with RandomForestClassifier,

So in order to classify, first you need to bin your target variable.

```
num_bins = 3
bin_boundaries = [0, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
car_data['Buy Rate'] = pd.cut(car_data['Buy Rate'], bins=num_bins, labels=False)
car_data['Buy Rate'] = car_data['Buy Rate'].map({0: 'Low', 1: 'Medium', 2: 'High'})
```

Result,

```
0     Medium
1     Medium
2        Low
.     
.
.
32      High
```

After binning you can train your data with RandomForestClassifier.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
car_data = pd.read_csv('car_data.csv')

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
car_data['Make'] = le.fit_transform(car_data['Make'])
car_data['Color'] = le.fit_transform(car_data['Color'])

num_bins = 3
bin_boundaries = [0, 0.5, 0.75, 1] 
car_data['Buy Rate'] = pd.cut(car_data['Buy Rate'], bins=num_bins, labels=False)
car_data['Buy Rate'] = car_data['Buy Rate'].map({0: 'Low', 1: 'Medium', 2: 'High'})

# Create X
X = car_data.drop('Buy Rate', axis=1)
# Create Y
y = car_data['Buy Rate'] # target variable

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.get_params()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Finally, this is how your code should be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The `X` variable you are passing to `.fit` must be a matrix with elements convertible to `np.float32`

From the [documentation on fit from sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.fit)

> fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)
>
> **X: {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)**
> The training input samples. Internally, its dtype will be converted to
> dtype=np.float32. If a sparse matrix is provided, it will be converted
> into a sparse csc_matrix.

You are probably trying to pass strings in the training data. The model can only be trained on numerical data, so all textual data must be converted to numerical data prior to training. To do so, you must encode the strings (textual data). There are multiple ways to do that, each with its pros and cons. You can read more about the topic and the different options available on sklearn in its documentation:

[scikit-learn | Preprocessing data: Encoding categorical features](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features)